# bash export command in powershell

Tags: django, bash, shell, azure, powershell

I'm trying to follow this guide to test Django on Azure:
https://github.com/carltongibson/rest-framework-tutorial/blob/master/docs/azure/2-appservice.md
, however I'm stuck at running the following command since I'm doing it from PowerShell:

`$ export $(grep -v '^#' .azure-env | xargs)`

What would the command be in PowerShell and can someone explain what it does ?

Thanks

Comment: `export` sets enviroment variables. You can do the same in powershell with `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable`. Take a look at: https://www.itprotoday.com/powershell/powershell-one-liner-creating-and-modifying-environment-variable

Comment: grep is removing comments from the file .azure-env and then exporting to shell

Comment: So how would I combine the regex, grep and environment variable with powershell ?

Comment: Well you can read the file first, remove the comments, and create Enviroment Variables with the provided lines then. Take a look at `Get-Content`, `Select-String`, `-split`. Maybe this points you in the right direction.

Comment: That command is fragile in `bash`; it assumes that none of the `key=value` pairs output by `xargs` will contain whitespace.

Comment: Any more questions? Or if it's helpful you can accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The description of the shell command is already in the document that you provide.

```
$ export $(grep -v '^#' .azure-env | xargs)
```

> This uses grep to go through your .azure-env file excluding any lines
>   that are comments, passing any values into `xargs` so they will be
>   formatted to be interpreted by the shell. We then export these so
>   they´re passed as environment variables to the commands we envoke.

And you can convert the shell command into PowerShell like this:

```
Get-Content .\azure.txt | Select-String -NotMatch "^#" | ForEach-Object { 
    $array= $_[0].ToString().split("=")
    [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable($array[0], $array[1])
    }
```

The screenshot of the result shows here:

[image]

Comment: sorry for the late reply, couldn't reply back back right away due to a long travel.

When I run the command I get the following error :

`Exception calling "SetEnvironmentVariable" with "2" argument(s): "String cannot be of zero length.
Parameter name: variable"
At line:3 char:5
+     [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable($array[0], $array[1] ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentException`

Comment: You need to make sure the environment variables in the right format as me: key=vaule.