# How to do "export PYTHONPATH=." on windows powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell

On a Linux session I can set an environment variable like

```
export PYTHONPATH=.
```

How to do that on a windows Powershell? I found [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54647001/bash-export-command-in-powershell) and tried

```
 [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable PYTHONPATH=.
```

and

```
$env PYTHONPATH=.
```

but neither did not work. In both cases I got an error `UnexpectedToken`.

Comment: What is `.` here(Current working directory)?

Comment: Yes. The "dot" indicates the curre3nt working directory. In Linux this is a valid and working expression. I want to define the PYTHONPATH for the current working directory in windows in the same way

Comment: You mean `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("PYTHONPATH", ".")`?

Comment: I am not sure `SetEnvironmentVariable ` will expand `.` as CWD. if not you probably have to use `$pwd` command. ie `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("PYTHONPATH", $pwd)`

Comment: Ah thanks! That works. I wonder why a lot of answers are posted which do not cover the complete solution ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$env:PYTHONPATH = $pwd
```

You forgot a colon in the last version. Also the . doesn't work here, but you can use the built-in variable $pwd (current directory).

I find **$env:NAME** the easiest way to get environment variables in Powershell. It also follows the Microsoft documentation: [about_Environment_Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables).